# How should I invoke Spin.js in AMD mode by using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, spinner, typescript

I have to implement a loading effect by using Spin.js. Below is my code:

```
/// <amd-dependency path="spin" />
export class SpinnerUtil {
    private target: HTMLElement;
    private spinner: Spinner;

    public constructor(target: HTMLElement) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public Spin() {
        var target = this.target;
        if (target.childElementCount == 0) {
            this.spinner = new Spinner().spin(target);
        }
    }

    public Stop() {
        this.spinner.stop();
        $(this.target).empty();
    }
}
```

I invoked it in another TypeScript file like this:

Initialization:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'javascripts',
paths: {
    'jquery': '../libraries/jquery/jquery-2.1.0',
    'spin': '../libraries/spin/spin-1.3.3'
},
```

Invoking:

```
import SP = require('utilities/Spin');

var spinnerId = 'spinnerView' + this.viewId;
this.$el.find('#spinnerView').attr('id', spinnerId);
var target: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(spinnerId);
this.spinner = new SP.SpinnerUtil(target);
this.spinner.Spin();
```

When I ran this application in the browser, it threw an error as below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Spinner is not defined.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Spin.js has been loaded in the context, but Spinner instance still can't be initialized.)

What should I do to fix this?

---

Hi,here's my simple testing code:

```
/// <reference path="../typing/require.d.ts" />

require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../libraries/jquery-2.1.0',
        'spin': '../libraries/spin-1.3.3'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },
        spin: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
}); 

//require(['jquery','spin'], ($,Spinner) => {
    $(function () {
        new Spinner().spin($('#content')[0]);
    });
//});
```

It works well, but if I remove this line 'require(['jquery','spin'], ($,Spinner) => {', it will throw an compile error"Could not find symbol 'Spinner'", how could I use Spinner without 'require' statement? Should I import something?

Comment: By "execute", do you mean "compile"?

Comment: Sorry, I mean when it runs.

Comment: Do you mean "when I compile" or "when I run the application in the browser"? It makes a huge difference

Comment: I mean "when I run the application in the browser", it can be compiled well.

Comment: The error means that `Spinner` is not recognized by the JavaScript interpreter, in human language: the spin.js file is not loaded properly. Can you post the JavaScript output?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the snapshot images in the description just now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here would be in the spin.js library that you are importing.  The library needs to attach the spin() function to JQuery ($) - so that the function spin() is available to any JQuery object.
You will need a shim in your require.config as follows:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'javascripts',
paths: {
    'jquery': '../libraries/jquery/jquery-2.1.0',
    'spin': '../libraries/spin/spin-1.3.3'
},
shim: {
spin: {
            exports: '$'
        }
}
```

This will extend the JQuery library functions to include the spin library functions.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I added another answer to describe my problem, would you please to see it?